# Spring Integration worker queue

Tags: spring-integration

I'm (very) new to Spring integration and looking to achieve the following;

- I have one channel - called the `work-channel`
- I have 3 distinct
  worker(s); `Alice`, `Bob`, `Claire`
- Alice, Bob & Claire each take between
  5-10 seconds to respond
- A `Message` is posted onto the `work-channel` and the work is deemed completed when process by an Alice, Bob and Claire and they can work in parallel
- There is 10 instances of each `Alice`, `Bob` & `Claire` (30 instances in total)

I'm simply looking to see what this pattern is called and what Endpoints you would use in Spring integration to be sure that all 3 workers process the request only ONCE and post their results to an `output-channel` but there are many workers listening on the same `work-channel` queue - I don't what to code something like an `AliceManager` and use  `threadexecutors` internally but have spring-integration handle the full concurrency - is this possible?

I will have a single gateway, e.g. `workersGateway.pushJobToWorks(job)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you say that you have only one entry point, but then you need to apportion each task by different services, so the [Router](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html) pattern is for you.

Further you can use [Executor Channel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel) for each worker and it will be the concurrency.

I suggest to read book on the matter: [EIP](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/), [Spring Integration in Action](http://www.manning.com/fisher/)

Comment: Thanks you mean have 3 Channels (AliceChannel/BobChannel/ClaireChannel) that are the Executor Channel and then route the worker-channel to those 3 channels?

Comment: Exactly! the router `input-channel` should be just dirrect one, and it is up to your logic which type of router to use, to determine the target worker channel